# Find all $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ such that $A=\{|a-b|:a,b\in A\}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For a set $A$ of real numbers, denote
$$A^\ast:=\{|a-b|:a,b\in A\}.$$

> **Question:** Find all finite subsets $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$
>   of the natural numbers such that
>   $$A^*=A.$$

**Attempt:** The empty set is a trivial solution, so let's assume $A\neq\emptyset$. Clearly, one must have $0\in A$. Also, it is clear that
$$A=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$$
is a solution for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. More generally,
$$A=\{0,k,2k,\ldots,nk\}$$
is a solution for any $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$. I am tempted to say that these are the only possible $A$, but not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The conjecture is correct.

Suppose $A=\{0,k,\ldots, s\}$ where $k$ is the smallest positive element of $A$, and $s$ is the largest.  Then $s-k\in A^\star=A$, and then $s-2k\in A$.  Continuing in this way, if $s$ is NOT a multiple of $k$, then $s-\alpha k$ will be in $(0,k)$ for some $\alpha$, which contradicts the choice of $k$.  Hence in fact $s$ is a multiple of $k$, and we have learned that $$\{0,k,2k,\ldots,nk\}\subseteq A$$
Suppose now there is some $m\in A$ that is not a multiple of $k$.  Since $\{0,k,\ldots, nk\}$ are each $k$ apart, $m$ must land in between two of them.  Hence, there is some $\alpha k\in A$ such that $0<|m-\alpha k|<k$.  But then $m-\alpha k\in A$, which again contradicts the choice of $k$.